# Renaming Cell References Based on Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba

I am interested in renaming my document's cell references to easily perform calculations in other sheets.  In the below code I am trying to name cell Di to the concatenation of the text in Ci and the year. I am using the below code and getting an error:

> Sub or Function Not Defined

Any ideas?

```
Sub Rename()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

For i = 1 To 50

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim str As String

    Set rng = Range("D" & i)
    rng.Name = Range("C" & i) & "_" & "2019"

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Try qualifying your `Range` references with the worksheet variable you have declared. `ws.Range` etc...

Comment: `ws.Names.Add Name:=Range("C" & i) & "_" & "2019", RefersTo:=rng`